# How to add a Visual Basic .NET syntax highlighting to CodeMirror editor?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, syntax-highlighting, codemirror

How to add a Visual Basic .NET syntax highlighting to CodeMirror editor? Does exists the mode for this language on any library? What should I correct except `keywords`, `blockKeywords` and `atoms`?

Pascal example:

```
CodeMirror.defineMode("pascal", function(config) {
  function words(str) {
    var obj = {}, words = str.split(" ");
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; ++i) obj[words[i]] = true;
    return obj;
  }
  var keywords = words("and array begin case const div do downto else end file for forward integer " +
                       "boolean char function goto if in label mod nil not of or packed procedure " +
                       "program record repeat set string then to type until var while with");
  var blockKeywords = words("case do else for if switch while struct then of");
  var atoms = {"null": true};

  var isOperatorChar = /[+\-*&%=<>!?|\/]/;
  var curPunc;

  function tokenBase(stream, state) {
    var ch = stream.next();
    if (ch == "#" && state.startOfLine) {
      stream.skipToEnd();
      return "meta";
    }
    if (ch == '"' || ch == "'") {
      state.tokenize = tokenString(ch);
      return state.tokenize(stream, state);
    }
    if (ch == "(" && stream.eat("*")) {
      state.tokenize = tokenComment;
      return tokenComment(stream, state);
    }
    if (/[\[\]{}\(\),;\:\.]/.test(ch)) {
      curPunc = ch;
      return null
    }
    if (/\d/.test(ch)) {
      stream.eatWhile(/[\w\.]/);
      return "number";
    }
    if (ch == "/") {
      if (stream.eat("/")) {
        stream.skipToEnd();
        return "comment";
      }
    }
    if (isOperatorChar.test(ch)) {
      stream.eatWhile(isOperatorChar);
      return "operator";
    }
    stream.eatWhile(/[\w\$_]/);
    var cur = stream.current();
    if (keywords.propertyIsEnumerable(cur)) {
      if (blockKeywords.propertyIsEnumerable(cur)) curPunc = "newstatement";
      return "keyword";
    }
    if (atoms.propertyIsEnumerable(cur)) return "atom";
    return "word";
  }

  function tokenString(quote) {
    return function(stream, state) {
      var escaped = false, next, end = false;
      while ((next = stream.next()) != null) {
        if (next == quote && !escaped) {end = true; break;}
        escaped = !escaped && next == "\\";
      }
      if (end || !escaped) state.tokenize = null;
      return "string";
    };
  }

  function tokenComment(stream, state) {
    var maybeEnd = false, ch;
    while (ch = stream.next()) {
      if (ch == ")" && maybeEnd) {
        state.tokenize = null;
        break;
      }
      maybeEnd = (ch == "*");
    }
    return "comment";
  }

  function Context(indented, column, type, align, prev) {
    this.indented = indented;
    this.column = column;
    this.type = type;
    this.align = align;
    this.prev = prev;
  }
  function pushContext(state, col, type) {
    return state.context = new Context(state.indented, col, type, null, state.context);
  }
  function popContext(state) {
    var t = state.context.type;
    if (t == ")" || t == "]" )
      state.indented = state.context.indented;
    return state.context = state.context.prev;
  }

  // Interface

  return {
    startState: function(basecolumn) {
      return {
        tokenize: null,
        context: new Context((basecolumn || 0) - config.indentUnit, 0, "top", false),
        indented: 0,
        startOfLine: true
      };
    },

    token: function(stream, state) {
      var ctx = state.context;
      if (stream.sol()) {
        if (ctx.align == null) ctx.align = false;
        state.indented = stream.indentation();
        state.startOfLine = true;
      }
      if (stream.eatSpace()) return null;
      curPunc = null;
      var style = (state.tokenize || tokenBase)(stream, state);
      if (style == "comment" || style == "meta") return style;
      if (ctx.align == null) ctx.align = true;

      if ((curPunc == ";" || curPunc == ":") && ctx.type == "statement") popContext(state);
      else if (curPunc == "[") pushContext(state, stream.column(), "]");
      else if (curPunc == "(") pushContext(state, stream.column(), ")");
      else if (curPunc == ctx.type) popContext(state);
      else if ( ctx.type == "top" || (ctx.type == "statement" && curPunc == "newstatement"))
        pushContext(state, stream.column(), "statement");
      state.startOfLine = false;
      return style;
    },

    electricChars: "{}"
  };
});

CodeMirror.defineMIME("text/x-pascal", "pascal");
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me - 
I added this definition in clike mode js file

```
CodeMirror.defineMIME("text/x-vb", {
    name: "clike",
    keywords: words("AddHandler AddressOf Alias And AndAlso Ansi As Assembly Auto Boolean ByRef Byte " + 
    "ByVal Call Case Catch CBool CByte CChar CDate CDec CDbl Char CInt Class CLng CObj Const CShort CSng CStr CType " +
    "Date Decimal Declare Default Delegate Dim DirectCast Do Double Each Else ElseIf End Enum Erase Error Event Exit False Finally "+
    "For Friend Function Get GetType GoSub GoTo Handles If Implements Imports In Inherits Integer Interface Is " +
    "Let Lib Like Long Loop Me Mod Module MustInherit MustOverride MyBase MyClass Namespace New Next Not "+
    "Nothing NotInheritable NotOverridable Object On Option Optional Or OrElse Overloads Overridable Overrides " +
    "ParamArray Preserve Private Property Protected Public RaiseEvent ReadOnly ReDim REM RemoveHandler Resume " +
    "Return Select Set Shadows Shared Short Single Static Step Stop String Structure Sub SyncLock Then Throw " +
    "To True Try TypeOf Unicode Until Variant When While With WithEvents WriteOnly Xor"),
    //blockKeywords: words("catch class do else finally for if switch try while"),
    atoms: words("True False Null"),
    hooks: {
      "@": function(stream, state) {
        stream.eatWhile(/[\w\$_]/);
        return "meta";
      }
    }
  });
```